# Optimize text rendering in the canvas - the rendering speed of truetype versus bitmap fonts

Tags: javascript, html, performance, fonts, html5-canvas

I profiled a canvas-based app I'm working on (linkurious.js) and I discovered than the main bottleneck is the text rendering currently.

So, for now I use `fillText()` to render the text but:

- Would it be more efficient to use bitmap fonts ?
- Distance fields ?
- Do the browser already optimize font rendering enough that I shouldn't try to beat them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all rendering text, especially vector-based, is hard. You probably couldn't beat the browser even with WebGL based implementation, as the browser font rendering is pretty optimized (browsers have been rendering fonts since 1994).

In theory, if the text doesn't change, the browser / font engine should recreate and cache all rendered glyphs in GPU memory and then just blit them out from there as bitmaps.

So if the text is the performance bottleneck bitmap fonts become an option. There are plenty of downsides, but speed is not one of them. After all, this was how the computers of 90s managed to produce any text on the screen at all.

Comment: So, using bitmap fonts would beat the GPU caching of the pre-rendered fonts ?

Comment: In theory it should not. But it depends what kind of text you are rendering, how much, how often it changes. The only way to know is to write the code and benchmark across different browsers.

Comment: Thanks, last question: Can I use a bitmap font directly (as a .ttf for example) or should I use my own renderer with a pre-generated bitmap font atlas ?

Comment: You need to pre-generate TTF -> bitmap spritesheet either offline or on application startup.

Comment: Save yourself the hassle and don't use a sprite sheet font. Create a buffer for the text you want to display, draw the text to that buffer and render just that buffer to your canvas. Rendering text isn't slow when it only happens once, its when you call fillText every frame call that you see the performance issues.

Comment: For history: I found the real bottleneck: setting `context.font` for each text made the render 2 times slower.